# How to specify a composite primary key using EFCore Code First Migrations

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations, composite-primary-key, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I'm using Asp.Net Core 2.1, Mvc, c#, EF Core with Code First and Migrations.

I'm trying to build a table that has a composite primary key in the `Migration.Up()` method:

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "TagValueAttributes",
    columns: table => new {
        TagValueID = table.Column<Int64>(nullable: false),
        Identifier = table.Column<string>(nullable: false, unicode: true, maxLength: 256),
        Value = table.Column<string>(nullable: true, unicode: true, maxLength: 2048)
    },
    constraints: table => {
        table.PrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_TagValueAttributes",
            columns: // what goes here???
        )
    }
);
```

I don't know what to specify for the `columns` parameter of the `constraints` `table.PrimaryKey()` call.  I would like columns `TagValueID`, and `Identifier` to form the composite key.

What do I need to specify for the `columns` parameter?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Why do you want to put this in the `Migration.Up()` method ?

You can do this via the Fluent API in your `DbContext` by overriding `OnModelCreating()` method :

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<TagValueAttributes>().HasKey(t => new { t.TagValueID, t.Identifier });
}
```

If you want tho keep this in `Migration.Up()` then do:

```cs
table.PrimaryKey(
    name: "PK_TagValueAttributes",
    columns: t => new { t.Identifier, t.TagValueID }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  However, there does not appear to be a property of `table` called `TagValueID` not one called `Identifier`.

Comment: I want this in `Migration.Up()` because I'm using migrations.  If I put it in `DbContext.OnModelCreating()` then I don't get to use Migrations.

Comment: Mmmmh okay I removed this part of the answer, I'll be back to you in minutes with a solution I hope.

Comment: You were very close.  I'm going to fix your answer and accept it.

Comment: Found the solution on my side a few seconds ago. Glad your problem was solved have a nice day.

Answer (score 11):

Using `EF Core 7.0` you can use data annotations
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

[PrimaryKey(nameof(Identifier), nameof(TagValueID))]
internal class table
{
    public Int64 Identifier { get; set; }
    public string TagValueID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: PrimaryKey is under which name space? 
PrimaryKeyAttribute could not be found error is throwing even using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

Comment: @ZinMin, the only namespace I am using is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`. Again, Microsoft introduced the **PrimaryKey** attribute in EF Core 7.0 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#configuring-a-primary-key)

Comment: @ZinMin Took me a moment time to find it, but you have to install the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions package to use it.